# Check if key exist in array by pushing values

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why everytime I want to check if a key is avalaible inside my array the result that I get is `false`? See my example below

```js
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });

//var inobject = "name" in obj; // result: false
//var inobject = "test1" in obj; // result: false
//var inobject = "10" in obj; // result: false
var inobject = "value" in obj;

$('body').append("<p>"+ inobject + "</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can't check for property `"name" in obj` against an array

Comment: Well, `obj` is an array, despite of it's name, and arrays don't have named keys. This array consists of objects, and you could do `"value" in obj[0]` to check if the first item in the array, which is an object, has the key "value" etc.

Comment: because you are trying to find a key of a element of the array. this will not work. consider using: `obj.filter((e)=>{return e.value == 10}).length > 0` if you are loocking for an element with the value 10.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you're trying to do we could better help you.

Comment: @Bellian Your solution did the trick. Thank you! Can you place it as an answer?

Comment: @adeneo Arrays in js are just objects like everything else. They DO have named keys: for example, all of the fancy method names we call on them (`push`,`map`, forEach`, etc). And you can add to your array as many arbitrarily named keys as you want, they just won't be noticed by the native array methods.

Comment: @skylize - You're wrong. Arrays have numeric indices, not named keys. Even if arrays are of type object, and have prototyped methods, and you technically can add properties to them, they do still not have named keys and values like an ordinary object, and one generally shouldn't use them as objects, but as the arrays they are intended to be.

Comment: You are wrong @adeneo. `let arr = ['purple'];  arr.purple = 5;  Object.keys(arr) \\ returns ['0', 'purple']`. The numbered indices are just named keys that have special meaning to the methods of `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @skylize - I didn't say you *couldn't* add properties to arrays, in fact I wrote the opposite, that you can. However you generally shouldn't. Firstly, because there are at least two other structures to choose from *(objects and maps)* if you want named keys, and secondly because you're just f**cking up an array out of ignorance because you couldn't be bothered to either use the correct data stucture or stick with numeric indices in your array, as it was intended.

Comment: @adeneo I absolutely agree that most attempts to add non-index property to array will only make your code confusing for no reason. But that doesn't change need to understand that underneath: an `array` is an `object`, a `map` is an object, an `object` is an `object`, a `string` is an `object`. This is a unique to javascript, making things behave differently here than other languages. The statement "Arrays have numeric indices, not named keys" is fundamentally incorrect in javascript. But once we understand that it's wrong we can usually just pretend it's right and be better for it. 

Comment: No, it's completely correct, arrays have numeric indexes. Arrays are also of type `object`, and you can add properties to them, but then you're not using the "array" part, but you're using the "object" part, it's different. It's in the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4), where it clearly states that a property is only an array index if certain conditions are met, otherwise it's not an array index, but just a regular property, and we have objects for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only search for keys of the array or values like this:

```js
var obj = new Array(),
  el1, el2

obj.push(el1 = { name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push(el2 ={ name: "test2", value: "40" });

$('body').append("<p>check for key 1: "+ (1 in obj) + "</p>");
$('body').append("<p>check for element el1: "+ (obj.indexOf(el1) >= 0) + "</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are searching an element inside the array that meets other criteria you have to do something like this:

```js
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });

// direct object access
var inobject = obj.filter((e)=>{ return 'value' in e && e.value == 10}).length > 0;

// deconstruct elements for better readability (WARNING: object deconstruction is not supported in all browsers yet!)
var inobject2 = obj.filter(({name, value})=>{ return 'value' !=undefined && value == 10}).length > 0;

$('body').append("<p>Search for element with value = 10: "+ inobject + "</p>");
$('body').append("<p>Search for element with value = 10: "+ inobject2 + "</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if "value" exists in the array and not in elements of your array. To correctly check if "value" exists in an element of the array you need to address `obj[i]`. Like this:

```
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });
var inobject = "value" in obj[0];
console.log(inobject);
```

Comment: yep but I do not want to check the first object. I want to check every name inside my object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a key exist in any of the object, (first level) in a collection then instead of doing 
`"value" in obj;` you can do `obj.some(e=> "value" in o);`

```js
//name is obj but its actually a array
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });


function checkForKey(list, key) {
   return list.some(e => key in e);
}

console.log('Key [name]:', checkForKey(obj, 'name'));
console.log('Key [age]:', checkForKey(obj, 'age'));
console.log('Key [value]:', checkForKey(obj, 'value'));
```

If you are looking at any level, inside either an array or object recursively, then try this, (not much performance efficient but easy to manipulate)

```js
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });

function checkForKeyNested(list, key) {
    try {
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list), function(k, v){
        if(key===k) {
            flag=true;
            throw 0;
        }
        return v;
    });
    } catch(ex) { return true;}
    return false;
}

console.log('Key [name]:', checkForKeyNested(obj, 'name'));
console.log('Key [age]:', checkForKeyNested(obj, 'age'));
console.log('Key [value]:', checkForKeyNested(obj, 'value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `"value" in obj` isn't the way you check a value's existence in an array, and you have an array of objects, which means you have to check the existence against the array's elements not the array itself, this is how you do it :

```js
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });
var inobject = obj.some((a) => "value" in a);
console.log(inobject); // true, means it's there
```

If you want to get the elements that have the key "value", use :

```js
var obj = new Array();
obj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });
obj.push({ name: "test2", AnotherKey: "60" });
var objects = obj.filter((a) => "value" in a);
console.log(objects); // test1 and test2
```

Comment: .filter(..).length is unneccessary here. It always has O(n), while .some(..) has O(n) worst case only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to check if the key exists on the Array, rather than on the objects within the array, so as expected those keys do not match as they don't exist on the array.

If you are trying to check if any objects within an array has a specific key, then you can do this with a simple loop:

```
var found = false;
var search = "value";
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    if(search in obj[i]){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Or separate it into a nice function:

```
function doesKeyExist(var arr, var key){
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        if(key in obj[i])
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var inobject = doesKeyExist(obj, "value");
$('body').append("<p>"+ inobject + "</p>");
```

---

If you want to find the **value** of a property, you can do this:

```
function doesValueExistForKey(var arr, var key, var search){
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        if(key in obj[i] && obj[i][key] === search)
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var inobject = doesValueExistForKey(obj, "name", "test1");
$('body').append("<p>"+ inobject + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You May try for this.

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name='t1';
obj.value='t2';

obj.hasOwnProperty('value'); // Return true if exist otherwise false
```

Comment: you can also,:

function lookup( name ) {
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if( arr[ i ].key === name )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if( !lookup( 'key1' ) ) {
    arr.push({
        key: 'key1',
        value: 'z'
    });
}

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator checks for property key names of the object it is called on. You can use it on the objects you pushed into the array, or use it with the array indexes.

```js
// a little nano-sized test suite made on the fly :)
const passed = document.getElementById('passed')
const assert = test => {
  if (!test) throw 'invalid assertion'
  passed.innerText = +passed.innerText + 1
}

// creates an Object that inherits from Array.prototype
var obj = new Array()

// Append an object {name, value} to the array
// 
obj.push({
  name: 'test1',
  value: 10
})

// Add a property to the array-object called value
obj.value = 40

assert('name' in obj === false)
assert('value' in obj === true)
assert(0 in obj === true)
assert('name' in obj[0] === true)
```

```html
<p><span id='passed'>0</span> tests passed</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an array of objects.  Several ways to do this, but let's simply create a lookup and lookupAll function and use it: (they both return arrays of objects)  the others return index and indexes array - changes if you sort.  Note this works, even in very much ugly older browsers like IE6.

```js
// create a namespace for my functions
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.arrayObj = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, property, searchTerm) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  }
};

var myobj = [{ name: "friend", value: "17" }];// better than new Array()
myobj.push({ name: "test1", value: "10" });
myobj.push({ name: "test2", value: "40" });
console.log(myobj);
// array of all matches
var allones = myApp.arrayObj.lookupAll(myobj, "test1", "name");
console.log(allones.length);// 1

// returns array of 1 
var firstone = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myobj, "friend", "name",true);
console.log(firstone[0].value);//17
```

Answer (score 0):

The *in* operator checks for *keys*. Your array has the following keys:

```
0,1
```

So

```
 0 in obj
```

is true.